# How to run parallel Cypress tests in NX with Github Actions?

Tags: parallel-processing, cypress, e2e-testing, nrwl-nx

I am setting up cypress e2e tests in an NX mono repo for the first time. I cannot get the tests to run in parallel. Currently, there are two apps: `App-A` and `App-B` in our repo. We also have two cypress apps: `App-A-e2e` and `App-B-e2e`.

Here is what our GitHub actions workflows look like:

main.yaml (only including the cypress jobs)

```
    cypress-staging-run:
    needs: deploy-staging
    uses: ./.github/workflows/cypress-run.yaml
    with:
      test_environment: staging
      cypress_tag: staging
    secrets: inherit

  cypress-production-run:
    needs: deploy-production
    uses: ./.github/workflows/cypress-run.yaml
    with:
      test_environment: production
      cypress_tag: production
    secrets: inherit
```

cypress-run.yaml

```
name: Run Cypress Tests

on:
  workflow_call:
    inputs:
      test_environment:
        required: true
        type: string
      cypress_tag:
        required: true
        type: string
    secrets:
      MY_SECRET:
        required: true

jobs:
  cypress-run:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout Repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0

      - name: Derive shas used for base and head required by nx affected commands
        uses: nrwl/nx-set-shas@v3

      - name: Setup Node
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: 16

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: yarn setup:ci

      - name: Cypress Run
        uses: cypress-io/github-action@v5
        with:
          command: yarn e2e:ci --configuration=${{ inputs.test_environment }} --tag ${{ inputs.cypress_tag }}
       **Tried adding parallel: true here, but it was not recognized- in CI showed parallel: false**
        env:
          CYPRESS_fileConfig: ${{ inputs.test_environment }}
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          MY_SECRET: ${{ secrets.MY_SECRET }}
```

package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "e2e:ci": "nx affected --target=e2e",
```

I tried adding `--parallel` and `-- --parallel` to the script or adding parallel: true to each app's project.json:

```
"targets": {
    "e2e": {
      "executor": "@nrwl/cypress:cypress",
      "options": {
        "cypressConfig": "apps/app-a-e2e/cypress.config.ts",
        "testingType": "e2e",
        "browser": "chrome",
        "record": true,
        "key": "record key here",
        "parallel": true
      },
```

In both cases, I get the same error:

```
You passed the --parallel flag, but we do not parallelize tests across different environments.

This machine is sending different environment parameters than the first machine that started this parallel run.

The existing run is: "URL here"

In order to run in parallel mode each machine must send identical environment parameters such as:

 - specs
 - osName
 - osVersion
 - browserName
 - browserVersion (major)

This machine sent the following parameters:

{
  "osName": "linux",
  "osVersion": "Ubuntu - ",
  "browserName": "Chrome",
  "browserVersion": "111.0.5563.146",
  "differentSpecs": {
    "added": [
      "src/e2e/app-a-test-1.cy.ts",
      "src/e2e/app-a-test-2.cy.ts",
      "src/e2e/app-a-test-3.cy.ts",
    ],
    "missing": [
      "src/e2e/app-b-test-1.cy.ts"
    ]
  }
}
```

So it seems like because app-a-e2e and app-b-e2e have different tests I can't run them in parallel. I then tried splitting up my cypress run into two separate jobs in the hopes that I could run App-A-e2e tests in parallel and then when that is done run App-B-e2e tests in parallel, but I got the same error.
I feel like I have read every documentation I can find, but I'm still unclear on how to run the tests in parallel. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

How does the `project.json` for each of the projects look like?

what is the server target for the respective executors?

Try to set a dedicated port for whatever target you want to test against.

`devServerTarget` is what you are looking for in the e2e configuration, this should point to respectively `App-A` and `App-B`.
Here you can set a port for the configuration of the target.